# Alternate definition of higher characteristic classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

While I was trying to find out why the first stiefel whitney class of a vector bundle is zero iff its orientable, I figured out that $w_1(Bundle)=w_1(Top\,exterior\,power\,of\,bundle)$ which is zero if the vector bundle is orientable. I did this using the kunneth formula for the exterior power of a direct sum and the formula for the characteristic classes of a tensor product of line bundles.

Question:  Given a real vector bundle $E \to B$, is $w_i(E)=w_1(\Lambda^i E)$?

Comment: The equation you've written doesn't make sense, since $w^i\in H^i$ and $w_1\in H^1$.

Comment: sorry :)  can I delete this question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP wanted to delete the question but they are no longer active.